# Are Immutable named parameters (with defaults) possible in Typescript (compile time)?

Tags: typescript, parameters, immutability, optional-parameters, default-parameters

The following example (which unfortunately doesn't work) should illustrate this question:

```js
function test({ name = 'Bob', age = 18 }: { readonly name?: string, readonly age?: number }) {
  // this should result in an error (but doesn't):
  name = 'Lisa';
}
```

This interesting [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/compile-time-immutability-in-typescript/) has some infos how to achieve Immutability with parameters, but AFAIK, this doesn't work with default parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider this a workaround, but you're not really passing 'named parameters', you are passing an object.

So this can be fairly easily rewritten as:

```js
function test(args: { name?: string, age?: number }) {
  const { name = 'Bob', age = 18 } = args;
  // this will error
  name = 'Lisa';
}
```

The reason `readonly` doesn't carry over, is because you're creating entirely new variables. `readonly` only applies to the object's properties, but not their values.

Comment: Thanks, your solution comes very close to the optimum (which would be as you mentioned, *real* named parameters)!
Indeed they are not default parameters, but it's AFAIK the closest to default parameters.